React Native Jest Snapshot Test not showing css styles

box.js file

import {View} from 'react-native';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  border,
  color,
  compose,
  flexbox,
  layout,
  overflow,
  position,
  size,
  space,
  variant,
} from 'styled-system';

const Box = styled(View)`
  ${variant({
    variants: {
      input: {
        width: '100%',
        paddingLeft: 18,
        paddingRight: 56,
        height: 56,
        fontSize: 16,
        backgroundColor: 'inputBackground',
        color: 'text',
        borderRadius: 16,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      priceInput: {
        width: '100%',
        paddingLeft: 18,
        paddingRight: 18,
        height: 56,
        fontSize: 16,
        backgroundColor: 'inputBackground',
        color: 'text',
        borderRadius: 16,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    },
  })}
  ${compose(color, layout, space, flexbox, overflow, position, border, size)}
`;

Box.defaultProps = {
  variant: 'default',
};

export default Box;


box.test.js

import 'jest-styled-components';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Box from '../box';

describe('Box Component', () => {
  it('renders correctly with default variant', () => {
    const { toJSON } = render(<Box>Default Content</Box>);
    expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('renders correctly with input variant', () => {
    const { toJSON } = render(<Box variant="input">Input Content</Box>);
    expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('renders correctly with priceInput variant', () => {
    const { toJSON } = render(<Box variant="priceInput">Price Input Content</Box>);
    expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});


box.test.js.snap

// Jest Snapshot v1, 

exports[`Box Component renders correctly with default variant 1`] = `
<View
  className="cRUOuD"
  variant="default"
>
  Default Content
</View>
`;

exports[`Box Component renders correctly with input variant 1`] = `
<View
  className="iVmpTQ"
  variant="input"
>
  Input Content
</View>
`;

exports[`Box Component renders correctly with priceInput variant 1`] = `
<View
  className="dXjrZi"
  variant="priceInput"
>
  Price Input Content
</View>
`;

Hello. I was asked to write snapshot tests for my mobile application in React Native. I am quite new in this field. I wrote the snapshot test you see using Chatgpt, and when I checked it on the web, I could not find any differences with other codes. I just noticed that it does not show CSS styles as output. Is this a bug or should it happen? Is this the required output? If CSS styles need to be displayed, how can I solve this problem? I am looking forward to your help. Thank you.
